# Active Admin, How can I see if a radio button is selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

```
f.input :rol, as: :radio, :label => "Rol", :collection => [ 'leerling', 'leraar' ]
```

So how do I know when one of the radio buttons is selected, because when 'leerling' is selected it needs to show a specific part of the form

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery >= 1.6**

```
$("#rol").prop('checked', true);
```

**jQuery < 1.6**

```
    $("#rol").attr('checked', true);
```

use distinct `id` or `class` to check this property